# Haskell: Turtle: command line parser

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I've been trying to build a command line parser with Turtle, nothing fancy: https://github.com/Tyrn/go-procr

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Turtle
import Prelude hiding (FilePath)

parserSwitch :: Parser (Bool, Bool)
parserSwitch = (,) <$> switch "verbose" 'v' "Unless verbose, just progress bar is shown"
                   <*> switch "filetitle" 'f' "Use file name for title tag"

parserArg :: Parser (FilePath, FilePath)
parserArg = (,)    <$> argPath "src" "Source directory"
                   <*> argPath "dst" "Destination directory"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (verbose, filetitle) <- options "Flags" parserSwitch
  echo (format ("verbose: "%w) verbose)
  echo (format ("filetitle: "%w) filetitle)
  (src, dst) <- options "Args" parserArg
  echo (format ("src: "%fp) src)
  echo (format ("dst: "%fp) dst)
```

There are three kinds of arguments required: boolean flags; options, text and integer; positional arguments. So far I got stuck at boolean flags and positional arguments. Unfortunately, the examples seem to be too basic even for this.

1. Do I really have to build separate parsers for different kinds of options (I did not manage to satisfy syntax with a single parser)?
2. It won't work as expected, anyway.

I can't figure out what my next step should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first step is to have something where you can store and retrieve your options easily:

```
data Settings = Settings
   { settingsVerbose      :: Bool
   , settingsFileTitle    :: Bool
   , settingsSource       :: FilePath
   , settingsDestination  :: FilePath
   }
```

Afterwards, you write parsers for your options. To make things clear, let's be a little bit verbose first:

```
verboseParser :: Parser Bool
verboseParser = switch "verbose" 'v' "Be more verbose"

fileTitleParser :: Parser Bool
fileTitleParser = switch "filetitle" 'f' "..."

sourceParser :: Parser FilePath
sourceParser = argPath "src" "Source directory"

destinationParser :: Parser FilePath
destinationParser = argPath "dst" "Destination directory"
```

Since `Parser` is an instance of `Applicative` we can then combine all options in a single parser:

```
settingsParser :: Parser Settings
settingsParser = 
    Settings <$> verboseParser
             <*> fileTitleParser
             <*> sourceParser
             <*> destinationParser
```

We've combined all four parsers into a single parser, similar to the combination via `(,)`. Now we can parse the options with a **single** call to `options`. After all, either all arguments are correct, or we have to present the user the proper usage:

```
main = do
   s <- options "Description of your program" settingsParser

   echo (format ("verbose: "%w)   (settingsVerbose s))
   echo (format ("filetitle: "%w) (settingsFileTitle s))
   echo (format ("src: "%fp)      (settingsSource s))
   echo (format ("dst: "%fp)      (settingsDestination s))
```

You probably want to use shorter names, though, and maybe write the parsers in `settingsParser`:

```
data Settings = Settings
   { sVerbose     :: Bool
   , sFileTitle   :: Bool
   , sSource      :: FilePath
   , sDestination :: FilePath
   }

settingsP :: Parser Settings
settingsP = 
  Settings <$> switch "verbose"   'v' "Be more verbose"
           <*> switch "filetitle" 'f' "..."
           <*> argPath "src" "Source directory"
           <*> argPath "dest" "Destination directory"

description :: Description
description = "Description of your program"

main = do
  (Settings verbose filetitle source dest) <- options description settingsP
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Zeta! The ```settingsP``` approach is excellent.